# PostAsJsonAsync of System.Net.Http.Formating is throwing System.NotImplementedException on Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, android, rest, xamarin

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = uri;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(route, requestResource).Result;
```

is not working with Xamarin PCL and causes this error:

```
ex = {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.FormattingUtilities' threw an exception. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporte...
```

Comment: Which Nuget Packages have you added? I installed `Microsoft.Net.Http` and `System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension` by `andre.agostinho` but didn't see  no-generic-type version of `PostAsJsonAsync`.

Comment: did you get an answer for the problem? I am having the same one

Comment: Got any solution for this ? Me too having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I have not used that method, but it's not implemented there isn't very much to do about it.

You can post like this though

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, route);
var hc = new StringContent(requestResource); // requestResource should be a string
hc.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json);
request.Content = hc;
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally that exception is thrown when a requested method or operation is not implemented. Check with the developer of the API if the method you are calling is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

try updating Visual Studio. That worked for me.